# Weak compactness and weak sequential compactness in Banach spaces

Tags: gn.general-topology, fa.functional-analysis

If $E$ is a Banach space, $A$ is a subset of $E$ and is compact with the weak topology $\sigma(E,E')$, that is the most coarse topology which make every $f\in E'$ continuous, is it true that $A$ is weakly sequentially compact?
As we all know, in $C_1$ spaces, compact concludes sequentially compact. So, we should show that $E$ is a $C_1$ spaces with the topology $\sigma(E,E')$.
Some known conclusions:$\forall x_0\in E$ , the basis of neighborhoods of $x_0$ constitutes of $V$ with the below form 
$$V=\lbrace x\in E;|(f_i,x-x_0)|\lt\epsilon, i\in I\rbrace$$
where I is a finite set.
Can we prove $E$ is a $C_1$ spaces?
Now, for every such $V$, we can find a $\delta>0$, such that $B(x_0,\delta)\subset V$.

Comment: What is *weak self sequence compact*? Do you mean weakly sequentially compact?

Comment: I think so, too. 

Comment: oh,yes, it is weakly sequentially compact

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's the  [Eberlein–Šmulian theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eberlein%E2%80%93%C5%A0mulian_theorem)

Comment: I don't think so. When $E=E'$, one can apply Ebelein-Smulian theorem.  